# Python - Why we should use mock to do test?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am very new to Python and I saw many projects on Github using Mock to do their test but I don't understand why.
  When we use mock, we construct a Mock object with a specific return_value, I don't truely understand why we do this. I know sometimes it is difficult to build our needed resources but what is the point if we construct a object/function with a certain return value ?

Comment: Its like a stub and driver..some else develops the stub we don't know implementation but we do know the outputs

Comment: In easy terms you think you are asked to develop average function ..but some body else develops add function..so you just use return of add to perform your average function

Comment: We want to test that _our_ code works correctly; we don't want to test the inner workings of an external resource.

Answer (score 0):

Mock can help to write unit tests. 
In unit tests, you want to test a small portion of your implementation. For example, as small as one function or one class.

In a moderately large software, these small parts depend on each other. Or sometimes there are external dependencies. You open files, do syscalls, or get external data in some other way.

While writing a directed unit test for a small portion of your code, you do not want to spend time to set-up everything else around it. (The files, syscalls, external data). Mock comes to your help there. With mock, you can make the other dependencies of your code behave exactly as you like. This way you can focus on testing your intended implementation.

Coming to the mock with the return value: Say you want to test `func_a`. And `func_a` calls `func_b`.  `func_b` does a lot of funky processing to calculate its return value. For example, talking to an external service, doing bunch of syscalls, or some other expensive operation. Since you are testing `func_a`, you only care about possible return values of `func_b`. (So that `func_a` can use them) In this scenario you would mock `func_b` and set the return values explicitly. This can really simplify your test complexity.